# Can I run low voltage undercabinet lighting wire under overhead microwave oven above the stove

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I would like to run low voltage undercabinet lighting wire (in PVC covering) under an overhead microwave oven above a gas stove. Otherwise, I would have to drill many holes in the cabinetry to go up and around the microwave oven to the bottom of the cabinet.

Comment: If the rest of your wiring is concealed inside the cabinets, having this bit exposed will scream "amateur DIY!" Drilling a few holes to do it right isn't really difficult and will _look_ a lot better (IMHO).

Comment: yes, you can. it will get greasy AF though, and may discolor if you cook small pots on a high flame. It should not catch fire though...

Comment: It is a very warm location and LED lights may not last long.

Answer (score 1):

It can get pretty hot above a range.   I've seen many range hoods with melted plastic parts on their fronts and side, and I've seen melted paint on the adjacent overhead cabinets.

I won't answer from an electrical safety or code perspective, because the other answer does that.   From a practical perspective, you should avoid doing this if you can.  There's a reasonable chance the wire will become heat-damaged, either melted or slowly becoming brittle and deteriorating from the high heat.

If the "wire" is not just wire but actual lighting strip, you'll also find it gets filthy, oily, and dulls the light.   You want range hood lights to have lenses that can easily be removed for cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

As far as code is concerned yes you can.
Have seen some very nice jobs where the strips in plastic were attached behind the front framework, just enough of a space so the one that was used could not be seen unless actually looking under the cabinets. I like the coated ones so they can be wiped off, I have seen the “tapes” of lights attached exposed and wonder how long those will work especially close to a stove. So your plan is starting out well if you can mount them well and have the control switch in a good location it can be a nice application.

Comment: I think OP is referring to the *wiring* and you are referring to the actual *lights*.

Comment: @manassehkatz yes to both. Low voltage is ok around water 15vac and 30vdc and below. these voltages are the low voltage contact limit so using exposed below kitchen cabinets is not a problem with code even exposed conductors are allowed below this limit and I have installed UL approved exposed conductor lighting usually 12vdc.